# Converting pandas dataframe to nested dictionary based on multi level header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

My csv file has a specific header where each field contains a database table name and column name which are delimited with a slash. Simple example:

```
user/username,user/email,user/name,address/country,address/city
```

I need to convert the pandas dataframe to a dictionary that looks like:

```
dict = {
    "user": {
        "username": "",
        "email": "",
        "name": ""
    },
    "address": {
        "country": "",
        "city": ""
    }
}
```

The easiest but not efficient way to do it was to convert the the dataframe to a dictionary using to_dict(orient='records') method, but obviously it gives not the desired output, so further processing needed to be done. Without touching the column names, i get a dictionary that looks like:

```
dict = {
    "user/username": "",
    "user/email":"",
    "user/name":"",
    "address/country":"",
    "address/city":"",
}
```

When splitting the header by delimiter, i get a multi level header, but the to_dict method gives a dictionary which haves a tuple as a key, so again processing needed to be done to get the desired output:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('/', expand=True)

dict = {
    ("user","username"): "",
    ("user","email"): "",
    ("user","name"): "",
    ("address","country"): "",
    ("address","city"): "",
}
```

I've also tried to iterate through rows with itertuples() but the column names are problematic. When i have a multi level header or when i leave it with the ,,/,, character, it replaces the column names with numbers (_1, _2, _3...).

So anyway, i have some overhead for a relatively simple task. When reading really big files, that overhead can be problematic.

I'm not a reagular pandas user, so i guess there is a simple way to do this task, but i was not able too google it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` to create `MultiIndex` columns then inside a dict comprehension traverse over `level=0` columns and use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient=records`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('/', expand=True)
dct = {k: df[k].to_dict('r') for k in df.columns.levels[0]}
```

Example:

```
print(df)
  user/username user/email user/name address/country address/city
0            A1         B1        C1              D1           E1
1            A2         B2        C2              D2           E2

print(dct)
{
    'address': [
        {'city': 'E1', 'country': 'D1'},
        {'city': 'E2', 'country': 'D2'}
    ],
    'user': [
        {'email': 'B1', 'name': 'C1', 'username': 'A1'},
        {'email': 'B2', 'name': 'C2', 'username': 'A2'}
    ]
}
```

---

**EDIT**: If need nested dictionaries for each row in the dataframe with the top level keys as `user` and `address`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(df):
    df = df.set_axis(
        df.columns.str.split('/', expand=True), 1)

    for d in df.to_dict('r'):
        dct = defaultdict(dict)
        for x, y in d:
            dct[x][y] = d[(x, y)]
        yield dict(dct)

dcts = list(f(df))
```

Result:

```
print(dcts)
[
    {
        'user': {'username': 'A1', 'email': 'B1', 'name': 'C1'},
        'address': {'country': 'D1', 'city': 'E1'}
    },
    {
        'user': {'username': 'A2', 'email': 'B2', 'name': 'C2'},
        'address': {'country': 'D2', 'city': 'E2'}
    }
]
```

Comment: Works. Thank you. I'm curious also, for a later need is there a way to convert every row to a dictionary. So the same output just the value for 'address' and 'user' key to be a single dictionary instead of having a list. So to have a 2 dictionaries as a result for your example?